# Utilizar @include para componentes

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy empezando en laravel, concretamente Laravel 8 y tengo algunas dudas de cómo incluir componentes en el DOM.

Anteriormente, en otro proyectos, para incluir por ejemplo un botón, utilizaba una clase llamada `Component` y dentro un método llamado `renderButton($texto)`
Por lo que en mi html hacia la llamada `Component::renderButton("Hola mundo")`

Actualmente en Laravel, estoy utilizando algo similar, creo una plantilla llamada `renderButton.blade.php`, y la llamo desde la plantilla haciendo `@include('renderButton', ['text' => 'Hola mundo'])`

Mi pregunta es:

¿Es esta una forma recomendable para crear componentes? ¿Hay alguna otra forma más sencilla para pintar estos componentes? y ¿Puede dar problemas de rendimiento tener 20 o 30 plantillas y llenar el html de `@include`?

Answer (score 0):

Buscando información, veo que Laravel tiene mejores soluciones para los componentes

Puedo sustituir el `@include` por `@component`

```html
@component('renderButton')
  @slot('text', 'Hola mundo')
@endcomponent
```

Comment: Si, aunque tambien puedes importarlo con este tag `<x-`. Mas informacion: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components